# File transfer in winforms using socket is not working when using client machines

Tags: winforms, file-transfer

This is my code for sending and receiving files.It is working when I am transferring files from server to local but when I am using any non server  machines, it is showing exceptions

> Background worker is currently busy.

```
private void BackgroundReceiveLogicMethod(BackgroundWorker bw)
    {

    Socket clientSock;
        try
        {

            string text=null;
            clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //clientSock.Blocking = true;
            textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                 {
                text=textBox2.Text;
                 });
            IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.Resolve(text);
            string[] aliases = IPHost.Aliases;
            IPAddress[] addr = IPHost.AddressList;

            IPEndPoint ipepServer = new IPEndPoint(addr[0], Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNo.Text));
            clientSock.Connect(ipepServer);

            lblReceivingMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                 {

                     lblReceivingMsg.Text = "Connected to the client";
                 });
            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
            try
            {
                // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
                if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\ShareIt\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\ShareIt\");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Fail silently
            }
            string receivedPath = @"D:\ShareIt\";

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);



            Console.WriteLine("Client:{0} connected & File {1} started received.", clientSock.RemoteEndPoint, fileName);
               lblReceivingMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                  {
                      lblReceivingMsg.Text = "Client"+clientSock.RemoteEndPoint +"connected & File"+ fileName+ "started receiving.... ";
                  });

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} received & saved at path: {1}", fileName, receivedPath);
          //  UpdateLabel(lblReceivingMsg, "File received and saved");
          //  UpdateLabel(label3, "Filename :" + " " + fileName);
         //   UpdateLabel(label4, "Path:" + " " + receivedPath);
            lblReceivingMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    lblReceivingMsg.Text = "File received and saved";
                });
            label3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                 {
                     label3.Text = "Filename :" + " " + fileName;
                 });
            label4.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                 {
                     label4.Text = "Path:" + " " + receivedPath;
                 });

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem connecting to server...");
            lblReceivingMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
              {

                  lblReceivingMsg.Text = "File Sending fail.....Restart the application";
              });
          //  Console.WriteLine("File Sending fail." + ex.Message);
            lblReason.Enabled = true;
            lblReason.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {

                lblReason.Text =  ex.Message;
            });

        }


    }
```

---

```
private void BackgroundSendingLogicMethod(BackgroundWorker bw)
    {

            string PathText = null;
            int prtNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNo1.Text);
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, prtNo);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            sock.Bind(ipEnd);
            lblMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lblMsg.Text = "Sharing started.....";
                    });
            sock.Listen(100);

            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        PathText = textBox1.Text; 
                    });

            label:
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PathText);

            string filePath1 = Path.GetFullPath(PathText);

            string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(PathText);//Your File Path;
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
            //lblMsg.Text = "Waiting for the client to receive";
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
            clientSock.Send(clientData);
            Console.WriteLine("File:{0} has been sent.", fileName);
          //  UpdateLabel(lblReceivingMsg,"File received.....");
            //UpdateLabel(lblMsg, "Sharing done.....");
            lblReceivingMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblReceivingMsg.Text ="File received....." ;
            });

            lblMsg.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
         {
             lblMsg.Text = "Sharing done.....";
         });
            // lblMsg.Text = "File has been sent." + fileName;


            clientSock.Close();
            goto label;
            Console.ReadLine();
      //   }



    }
```

There are two separate background workers are running.